# Firebase push notification in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am not receiving notifications after sending it through the Firebase console.

My code is running well in Marshmallow, but not working in Nougat. I'm using Firebase push notifications. Searched many sites, but did not get any solution.

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Comment: please post your code?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do include in your post the relevant code snippets (Android side) and some sample details (what you send through the Firebase Console) in order for us to help you further. I would also highly suggest that you [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you're unsure how to ask here. Cheers! :)

Comment: thank you for ur response but i solved it by adding 
android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" to manifest file